# Cannot connect to docker container from host on Mac

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

I want my ASP.NET Core web application to be hosted in a docker container, listening on port 80. So far I have the following Dockerfile for my project:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish PROJECT_NAME -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PROJECT_NAME.dll"]
```

I build my image:

```
docker build -t IMAGE_TAG -f PROJECT_NAME/Dockerfile .
```

Then I run my container:

```
docker run IMAGE_TAG -p 80:80
```

The console log shows it's running:

```
[18:54:34 INF] Starting web host.
[18:54:34 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:80
[18:54:34 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[18:54:34 INF] Hosting environment: Production
[18:54:34 INF] Content root path: /app
```

My web application has a health check endpoint of /api/health, which simply returns 'Healthy' to show all is well.

However when I go the browser and enter any of the following, nothing happens:

- http://localhost/api/health
- http://127.0.0.1/api/health
- http://0.0.0.0/api/health
- http://192.168.99.100/api/health
- http://docker.for.mac.localhost/api/health
- http://host.docker.internal/api/health

This is my first time messing around with docker, so it is likely I've missed something obvious. Have you any ideas?

Comment: If the `Dockerfile` has the program run on `127.0.0.1`, try setting it to run on `0.0.0.0`.